# python multiply list elements inside list

Tags: python, list

I use lists to randomly pick an element over many iterations (to create artificial data sets). To change the probability of getting a certain element, I'm repeatedly adding those elements that should have a higher change of being picked, so instead of

```
fair_list = ["A", "B", "C"]
```

I would do

```
unfair_list = ["A", "B", "C", "C", "C"]
```

Is there a better way to do this inline? I tried

```
unfair_list = ["A", "B", 3 * "C"]
```

but this results in

```
["A", "B", "CCC"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one line actually.

```
unfiar_list = ["A", "B", *["C"]*3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
unfair_list = ["A", "B"]
unfair_list += ["C"] * 3
```

or

```
unfair_list = ["A", "B"] + ["C"] * 3
```

so you will get

```
unfair_list = ["A", "B", "C", "C", "C"]
```